# create-react-app and Sass don't appear to be working

Tags: webpack, sass, create-react-app

I'm not sure but this worked perfectly fine a few months ago but now, it no longer seems to work. With React's `create-react-app` module, updating the `webpack.config.dev.js` to test for the following:

```
  {
    test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
    loader: 'style!css?importLoaders=1!postcss!sass'
  },
```

... with the dependencies `node-sass` and `sass-loader`, the `.scss` styles don't appear to be getting captured.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to also update the `url` loader within the webpack config to exclude `scss` files

```
    exclude: [
      /\.html$/,
      // We have to write /\.(js|jsx)(\?.*)?$/ rather than just /\.(js|jsx)$/
      // because you might change the hot reloading server from the custom one
      // to Webpack's built-in webpack-dev-server/client?/, which would not
      // get properly excluded by /\.(js|jsx)$/ because of the query string.
      // Webpack 2 fixes this, but for now we include this hack.
      // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1713
      /\.(js|jsx)(\?.*)?$/,
      /\.(css|scss)$/,
      /\.json$/,
      /\.svg$/
    ],
    loader: 'url',
    query: {
      limit: 10000,
      name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
    }
  },
```